# ASP.NET Control's UniqueID delimiter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

The UniqueID of a control is delemited with the '$', is it possble that the delimiter can change, and if so, is there a property somewhere that contains the delimiting character?

Comment: I would never depend on such things but rather stay with the ClientID/UniqueID properties. Perhaps the $ gets changed into another character some day. But perhaps it gets changed into say a sequence 5 characters... you'll never know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there are the `protected` properties [`IdSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.idseparator.aspx) and [`ClientIDSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidseparator.aspx), I would regard it as subject to change and avoid writing code that make assumptions that a certain character is used as separator. Both those properties are of the type `Char`, so I would find it unlikely that they would change into using multiple-character separators, but that is just an guess, and also something that I would avoid relying on.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is dangerous to rely on the exact character used as the delimiter.

I came across some legacy JavaScript code that was passed a UniqueID and parsed it like this:

```
theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = s.split(":")[0];
theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = s.split(":")[1];
```

Moving to a more recent version of the CLR caused this code to break because, as indicated in this question, the delimiter is now '$', not ':'.